# How can I add custom HTML-code in the TinyMCE toolbar?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to add this HTML:

```
<button ... class = "myclass" ...>
    <input type = "file" ...>
</button>
```

This button for quick loading image at server in my JS-function. Finally it will insert image to the TinyMCE caret position.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to create a custom TinyMCE plugin that will insert the image that you want.